# python - ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: python

Ради прикола решил написать посылальную машину (чисто от нефиг делать).
Вот код:

```
print('Новинка! Добавлено больше пасхалок!')
name = input('кого пошлём?')
if name == 'посылальная машина':
    print('быкуешь?')
elif name == 'привет':
    print('привет')
elif name == ('мама'):
    print('не надо так')
elif name == ('папа'):
    print('не надо так')
elif name == ('как дела?'):
    print('нормально, а у тебя?')
elif name == ('нормально') or ('тоже'):
    print('всё, поговорили и хватит, ты же сюда посылать пришёл(-а), верно?')
elif name == ('кот'):
    print('кота не трогай')
else:
    number = int(input('сколько раз будем посылать?'))
    if number == 0:
        print('ты вообще собираешься посылать?!')
    elif number == 666:
        print('с огнём играешь')
    elif number > 99999:
        print('много')
    else:
        print(name, 'успешно послан(-а)' number, 'раз(-а)!')   
for name in range(9999999999):
    name = input('кого пошлём?')
    if name == 'посылальная машина':
        print('быкуешь?')
    elif name == 'привет':
        print ('привет')
    elif name == ('мама'):
        print ('не надо так')
    elif name == ('папа'):
        print ('не надо так')
    elif name == ('как дела?'):
        print ('нормально, а у тебя?')
    elif name == ('нормально') or ('тоже'):
        print ('всё, поговорили и хватит, ты же сюда посылать пришёл(-а), верно?')
    elif name == ('кот'):
        print ('кота не трогай')
    else:
        number = int(input('сколько раз будем посылать?'))
        if number == 0:
            print ('ты вообще собираешься посылать?!')
        elif number == 666:
            print ('с огнём играешь')
        elif number > 99999:
            print ('много')
        else:
            print (name, 'успешно послан(-а)' number, 'раз(-а)')
ошибка здесь: (центральная строчка)
else:
    print(name, 'успешно послан(-а)' number, 'раз(-а)!') (ошибка здесь)
for name in range(9999999999):
```

Выделяет всю незаполненную часть строки. Я долго смотрел, искал ошибку,
пытался сам исправить, переписывал код, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку.
Можете помочь?

Comment: `'успешно послан(-а)' number` - параметры функции (print в данном случае) должны быть разделены запятой.

Comment: Советую вам удалить этот вопрос, так как, во-первых, его причиной является опечатка, что говорит о том, что он не будет полезен другим участникам сообщества, во-вторых, вам, на мой взгляд, следовало бы привести более адекватный пример, в-третьих, ваш вопрос можно, что называется, "привлечь" как "невежливый или оскорбительный".

Answer (score -2):

```py
print (name, 'успешно послан(-а)', number, 'раз(-а)')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте свой ответ. Код нужно писать внутри ` `, либо же после 4-х пробелов.

Comment: Ваш ответ не должен состоять из единственной строки. Вам следует отформатировать его, как написал @Mus1k и дополнить подробностями: что именно вы исправили и почему не работало так, как было у автора